# FlatList not rendering it showing anything other than FlatList

Tags: react-native

I was trying to render a list but it is not rendering if I try to render a text or an image it is rendering but the FlatList is not rendering this is the code that I have written

**

```
 return(
    <SafeAreaView  forceInset={{ top: 'always' }} >
        <Image
    style={styles.tinyLogo}
    source={require('../../assets/img.png')}
  />
  <Text> checking </Text> 
  <FlatList
      data={menu}
      renderItem={(item) => {
        return <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.key }
  />
    </SafeAreaView>
```

**

Comment: what's withiin `menu` data?

Comment: menu is an array const [menu] =[
   { name: 'Buy Medicine', key: '1' },
   { name: 'My Address', key: '2' },
   { name: 'Reminder', key: '3' },
   { name: 'Favourites', key: '4' },
   ];

Comment: it is solved  i was writing menu inside [] so it was not rendering because i was using an useState example so i forgot to also remove  [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your renderItem to this

```
renderItem={({item}) => {
  return <Text>{item.name}</Text>
}}
```